# CA1804: declares a variable never used

Tags: fxcop

I have a foreach loop that declares a variable I never use, but I don't know how to get around it.

```
foreach (string i in stringCollection){
    some other stuff
}
```

I never use "i" - but I need an iterator in the loop.  So how do I get rid of this error?

Comment: Why are you iterating a collection that you aren't using?

Comment: In short, I don't know! <facepalm />

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Warning is reasonable. You don't need `foreach` at all. Looks like you try to loop times equal to size of collection. You should use `for`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < stringCollection.Count; i++)
{
    some other stuff
}
```